# Else If statement never runs

Tags: javascript, if-statement, rect

So I'm trying to implement platforms for the game I'm making for a project (similar to falldown) and have created multiple arrays that have contain all the possible platforms (canvas is 360 so there is if platform[i] == 1 it draws a rect)

```js
var canvas;
var ctx;
var isPlaying = false;

window.onload = function(){
  canvas= document.getElementById("gamesCanvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var fps = 60;
  setInterval(function(){    
  }, 1000/fps);
  createMenu();
  canvas.addEventListener('click', getClicks.bind(this), false)
    //canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", getPos)    
}

function initialise(){
  isPlaying = true;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  createRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height, 'black');
  createPlatforms();
}

function createPlatforms(){
  x = randint(1,2);
  console.log(x)
  var i;
  var pos = -60;
  var platform1 = [0,1,1,1,1,1];
  var platform2 = [1,0,1,1,1,1];
  var platform3 = [1,1,0,1,1,1];
  var platform4 = [1,1,1,0,1,1];
  var platform5 = [1,1,1,1,0,1];
  var platform6 = [1,1,1,1,1,0];
  if(x==1){  
    for (i=0; i<platform1.length; ++i) {
      var pos = (pos+60); 
      if(platform1[i] == 1){
        createRect(pos, 60, 60,5, 'white');       
      }
    } 
  }
  else if(x==2){
    for (i=0; i<platform2.length; ++i){
      var pos = (pos+60);
      if (platform2[i] ==2){
        createRect(pos,60,75,5,'white');
      }
    }
  }
}

function randint(min, max) {
    return ~~(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

function background(color) {
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function createMenu(){
    background("black");
    if (!isPlaying) {
        ctx.font = "60px monospace";
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fillText("FallDown", 40, 130);

        ctx.font = "34px Arial";
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fillText("PLAY", 130, 260);

        ctx.font = "34px Arial";
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fillText("LEADERBOARD", 50, 340);

        ctx.font = "34px Arial";
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fillText("SETTINGS", 90, 420);
    }
}

function createRect(leftX, topY, width, height, color){
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(leftX, topY, width, height);

}

function getClicks(evt) {
    var x = evt.offsetX;
    var y = evt.offsetY;
    if ((x > 110 && x < 240) && (y > 220 && y < 275) && !isPlaying) {
        initialise()
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Falldown</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="gamesCanvas" width="360" height="640"></canvas>
    <!--script src="test.js"></script-->
  </body>
</html>
```

However, if x>1 (so basically an else if statement is required to run) it doesn't draw anything.

I was testing to see whether it is something that I could fix, however, all I managed to realise that if the if statement has got the contents of the else if statement than it will draw the rects in the right position so in this case (platform2) would be drawn.

I've managed to narrow down the problem but I'm not sure how to fix it. I have experience with python but have never experienced anything like this

Just letting you know that I can't just use the else statement as I have to implement 6 platforms and if I were to use just if and else than that would mean I could only draw 2 of the 6 platforms

Comment: use a switch statement?

Comment: please add the html part as well.

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with an else if statement, not the neatest or most effective way to achieve this, but there isn't anything wrong with the else if statement, I would log `x` to check it's value or hardcode it to debug your statements.

Comment: you are not handling x>1 condition in createPlatforms(). but question seems you are expecting run something when x>1, this is still confusing. clearly tell what is the question?

Comment: so from randint if x ==2 and the else if statement is supposed to run it doesn't

Comment: You need to debug with value of `x`

Comment: So I've been logging x value to the console and whenever it is 2 it doesn't run the else if

Though when I changed the if statement to x==2 and the else if to x==1 the else if didn't seem to run but the if did

Comment: I've placed a log for for x, and I've also placed a log for 1 & 2 inside each section.  When x = 1 , it logs 1,1  when it's 2 = logs 2,2.  So not really sure what problem your having.  The else is certainly firing..  Also looking at your code, you don't even need if else, or even switch.  Make your platforms into an array of array, and you can select the platform that way.

Comment: `if (platform2[i] ==2){`  , you obviously want this to equal '1', as your array is made up of 0 and 1's..  Saying this, your platform built script is way more complicated than it's required, it doesn't require the array, and it doesn't require the switch / if statements either..

Comment: @Keith Oh ok I guess that is why it wasn't drawing anything. My bad I should have actually read through the 2nd nested if statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial problem wasn't with the if / else.. but the if inside..

But with -> `if (platform2[i] ==2){`  this wanted to be `if (platform2[i] == 1){`

But saying all this, your createPlatforms was only creating a single platform.  It didn't really need any If/else or arrays.

Below I've modified createPlatforms, using just two for loops.

```js
var canvas;
var ctx;
var isPlaying = false;

window.onload = function(){
  canvas= document.getElementById("gamesCanvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var fps = 60;
  setInterval(function(){    
  }, 1000/fps);
  createMenu();
  canvas.addEventListener('click', getClicks.bind(this), false)
    //canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", getPos)    
}

function initialise(){
  isPlaying = true;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  createRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height, 'black');
  createPlatforms();
}

function createPlatforms(){
  for (var y = 0; y < 8; y ++) {
    var x = randint(0, 5), pos = 0;    
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i ++) {
      if (i !== x) {
        createRect(pos, 60 + y*60 ,75,5,'white');
      }
      pos += 60;
    } 
  }
}

function randint(min, max) {
    return ~~(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

function background(color) {
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function createMenu(){
    background("black");
    if (!isPlaying) {
        ctx.font = "60px monospace";
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fillText("FallDown", 40, 130);

        ctx.font = "34px Arial";
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fillText("PLAY", 130, 260);

        ctx.font = "34px Arial";
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fillText("LEADERBOARD", 50, 340);

        ctx.font = "34px Arial";
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fillText("SETTINGS", 90, 420);
    }
}

function createRect(leftX, topY, width, height, color){
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(leftX, topY, width, height);

}

function getClicks(evt) {
    var x = evt.offsetX;
    var y = evt.offsetY;
    if ((x > 110 && x < 240) && (y > 220 && y < 275) && !isPlaying) {
        initialise()
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Falldown</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="gamesCanvas" width="360" height="640"></canvas>
    <!--script src="test.js"></script-->
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`switch`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) statement in javascript to handle lots of cases.

Example:

```
switch(x){
    case 1: 
        //logic here
        break;
    case 2:
        // and so on
        break:
    default:
        break;
}
```

You can add as many cases as you would like. This will eliminate the need to use `if` `else`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there a reason why else if statements sometimes don't execute in js?

Comment: No there isn't, N. Ivanov is just `switch`ing your logic and suggesting a neater approach, but that doesn't solve why your else if logic isn't running